# Need help in convert .sh file to .bat

Tags: linux, windows, batch-file, sh

I have a java tool that runs on Linux and I am trying to get it running on Windows. Below is the `.sh` file for running the tool. Any help to convert it to a `.bat` will be highly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=./lib/client-log4j2.xml -cp ./lib/*: org.test.SdkClient "$@"

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Unable to execute SdkClient."
fi
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) including the link "How to ask questions the smart way."

Comment: Why not install msys or rewrite this in your scripting language of choice (ruby, python, perl). SO is for sharing something you have tried and need help with rather than asking someone to write something for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start with evaluating where the installed files went by opening a cmd window and issuing
`Dir /B /S /A "%USERPROFILE%\client-log4j2.xml`
looking at the path variable
`Set Path`
and
`Set Java_Home`.

Batch with no name? This is just an educated guess.

```
@Echo off
Rem java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=./lib/client-log4j2.xml -cp ./lib/*: org.test.SdkClient %*
java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=./lib/client-log4j2.xml org.test.SdkClient %*
If ErrorLevel 1 echo "Unable to execute SdkClient."
```

I don't know what that `-cp ./lib/*:` means.